# state in mapStateToProps is JSX! React / Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am a beginner in React/Redux and ran into this crazy problem where when I console.log the state of mapStateToProps(state), it logged some JSX.
To elaborate...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import BlogListItem from './blog_list_item';
import selectBlogs from '../selectors/blogs';

const BlogList = (props) => (
    <div className="content-container">
        <div className="list-header">
            <div className="show-for-mobile">Blogs</div>
            <div className="show-for-desktop">Blog</div>
            <div className="show-for-desktop">Posted on</div>
        </div>
        <div className="list-body">
            {
                props.blogs.length === 0 ? (
                    <p className="list-item list-item--message">No Blogs. Write one now!</p>
                ) : (
                    props.blogs.map((blog) => {
                        return <BlogListItem key={blog.id} {...blog} />;
                    })
                )
            }
        </div>
    </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state); // Logs out JSX here
    return {blogs: selectBlogs(state.blogs, state.filters)};
};

export default (mapStateToProps)(BlogList);
```

The console.log JSX is the following:

```
ƒ BlogList(props) {
return _react2.default.createElement(
    'div',
    { className: 'content-container' },
    _react2.default.createElement(
        'div',
        { className: 'list-header' },
        _react2.default.…
```

Which is exactly the const I have defined above!
Because of this the app won't run as the parameters passed into `selectBlogs()` become `undefined`.

(If any other details are needed please ask!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When exporting the connected instance, you missed the `connect` which is why you are getting the error

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BlogList);
```

Comment: Glad to have helped